# Sorting with lambda in Python with an additional function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm baffled by why this doesn't work.

I have a function called `value(word)` which returns an integer value for any string, e.g.: `value('chicken') = 53`.

Can `value()` be used within a lambda expression as a key to sort a list. In other words, can we do:

```
words = ['chicken', 'tiger', 'bee'] # values : 53, 59, 12
sorted(words, key=lambda x: value(x))
# output: ['tiger', 'chicken', 'bee']
```

I defined `value` as

```
def value(word): 
    return sum(ord(c) - 96 for c in word)
```

For some reason when I do this nothing is sorted.

Comment: Yup, I did try it :(

Comment: How do you define `value`?

Comment: I define it as : `def value(word):
    return sum(ord(c) - 96 for c in word)`

Comment: and my output ends up being: `[('bee', 12), ('chicken', 53), ('tiger', 59)]`which isn't sorted

Comment: Looks like you're expecting it to be descending, but you're actually seeing ascending order, which isn't quite "unsorted." Is that the issue here?

Comment: That is indeed sorted.  It is merely sorted the wrong direction.

Comment: When I run it I get `['bee', 'chicken', 'tiger']` with `chicken` = 53, `tiger` = 59, `bee` = 12. So its right.

Answer (score 1):

To get the order you expect, you need to sort in reverse order since the default is ascending order. You can use the `reverse` key word argument to do so. Also you can remove the `lambda` since `value` is *already* a function

```
def value(word):
    return sum(ord(c) - 96 for c in word)

words = ['chicken', 'tiger', 'bee']
S = sorted(words, key=value, reverse=True)
# ['tiger', 'chicken', 'bee']
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. As you say, it's equivalent to what the user already has.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working correctly:

```
sorted(words, key=lambda x: value(x))
```

The issue is likely either with your `value` function or the order of the sort. For instance, if your function is:

```
def value(s):
    return len(s)
```

then the `sorted()` function will return `['bee', 'tiger', 'chicken']`, since `len('bee') = 3`, `len('tiger') = 5`, and `len('chicken') = 7`.

If you want to reverse the order (make it descending), you would do:

```
sorted(words, key=lambda x: value(x), reverse=True)
```

Comment: @zondo That may be true, but I was working off the format provided in the original question, which _is_ correct the way it's provided, even if suboptimal. I should not be penalized for what is in fact a correct answer.

Comment: Certainly.  I don't know why you were downvoted.  I didn't do it.